# Restriction of a vector bundle

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, vector-bundles

I know that my question is closely related to this topic:
[Restriction of a smooth vector bundle is a smooth bundle?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930402/restriction-of-a-smooth-vector-bundle-is-a-smooth-bundle)

That is, given a vector bundle show that for a immersed/embedded submanifold the restriction defines a vector bundle by using the vector bundle chart lemma.

However, if I use the vector bundle chart lemma (as noted in the text) I really don't see any step wherein I need the injectivity of the differential map. That is, isn't a smooth mapping on M:
$$\tau_{\alpha, \beta}(p) \rightarrow GL(k,\mathbb{R})$$
still smooth when I introduce a "submanifold" S such that the inclusion mapping $S \mapsto M$ is smooth? In that sense, I don't understand where the condition on the rank of the differential is needed. It would be great if someone could point out my misunderstanding in the proof!

Comment: The notation $\tau_{\alpha,\beta}(p)\rightarrow GL(k,\mathbb{R})$ seems all over the place to me. I'm also not sure I understand the notion of "submanifold" you're suggesting. However, and I think this may be the core of your question, it is possible to pull back smooth bundles along *any* smooth map. However, it is only reasonable to call the pullback a "restriction" when the map is the inclusion of a smooth submanifold.